# How to select correct operator overload

Tags: c++, namespaces, operator-overloading, argument-dependent-lookup

I have this data and operator defined in `namespace a`:

```
namespace a {
enum class E {
    VALUE
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const E e)
{
    return os << "VALUE";
}
}
```

My code operates in `namespace b`, and it would like to use another `operator<<` for the same type, replacing the one originally defined in `namespace a`:

```
namespace b {

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const a::E e)
{
    return os << "value";
}

void f()
{
    const auto e = a::E::VALUE;
    std::cout << e << std::endl;
}
}

int main()
{
    b::f();
    return 0;
}
```

Because of ADL, compiler get confused and sees the call to `operator<<` as an ambiguous call, since both the `namespace a` and `namespace b` version are available.

How can I make it use my version of `operator<<` when user code is inside `namespace b` without ambiguity?

Comment: cant help myself but to note that it isnt the compiler that gets confused, but it does "the right thing", its just not what you expect ;). Does it have to be a `operator<<`, or would a named function do as well?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 with function is easier to specify which overload of the function one wants to use, that's why I put the question in term of operator overloading, even if the problem is the same: even with functions, I would like not to specify every time which overload to use, I would like to specify it only once.

Comment: Really the answer is that only namespace `a` has the "right" to define the canonical `operator<<` for the type `a::E`. The `operator<<` in namespace `b` should be changed to a named function.

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
namespace b {

template<class T>
struct Wrapper { T value; };

template<class T>
inline Wrapper<T> wrap(T t) {
    return {t};
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Wrapper<a::E> e) {
    return os << "value";
}

void f() {
    const auto e = a::E::VALUE;
    std::cout << wrap(e) << std::endl;
}

} // namespace b
```

Alternatively, with reusable `Wrapper`:

```
template<class Tag, class T>
struct Wrapper { T value; };

template<class Tag, class T>
inline Wrapper<Tag, T> wrap(T t) {
    return Wrapper<Tag, T>{t};
}

namespace b {

struct Tag {};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Wrapper<Tag, a::E> e) {
    return os << "value";
}

void f() {
    const auto e = a::E::VALUE;
    std::cout << wrap<Tag>(e) << std::endl;
}

} // namespace b
```

Comment: wrap() needs to be written every time. Isn't there a way to specify only once that I want always to use the `namespace b` version of `operator<<` while inside `namespace b`?

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 Added a version with reusable `Wrapper` for you.

Comment: For example, I tried adding `using b::operator<<;` before the operator call, but it did not solve the ambiguity.

Comment: With C++17, function `wrap` is mostly unneeded, `Wrapper{e}`/`Wrapper{Tag{}, e}` would be enough.

Comment: Your wrapper does copy BTW. (not problematic for enum, but might be for custom classes).

Comment: @Jarod42 It does for the simplicity of exposition. Feel free to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

To remove ambiguity, you might full qualify the call:

`b::operator <<(std::cout, e) << std::endl;`

Not really fine with operator though, I agree.